# At the end of the first mission on Mars, is it possible to catch the Cerberus agent?

Tags: mass-effect-3

At the end of the mission on Mars, a Cerberus agent is running away with the data about the Prothean device. I was unable to catch her. Is it possible to catch up with her before she reaches her shuttle and does it matter if I do?

Comment: By, "Unable to catch her", you mean "got into the shuttle and had to be knocked down by James?"

Comment: @RavenDreamer yes, exactly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't catch her. As a Vanguard, I used Charge to stay within 0-5 meters of her through the entire chase with no effect. She will always reach her shuttle and trigger the cutscene that follows.

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible to "catch" her during the chase as what what follows is part of the storyline.