# Is there any meaningful way to affect the Cerberus agent chase scene?

Tags: mass-effect-3

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53804/at-the-end-of-the-first-mission-on-mars-is-it-possible-to-catch-the-cerberus-ag) I understand that you can't actually catch her. However, at the end of the chase I think I was awarded experience. Is there anything you can do during the chase scene to increase the experience gained by this encounter and can your actions at any point during this encounter change the way the cut scene unfolds? Also, what happens if the Cerberus agent gets too close (out of instinct I just shot her until she wasn't coming for me)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [At the end of the first mission on Mars, is it possible to catch the Cerberus agent?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53804/13314)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't change the way it unfolds.
If you get too close when following then she will attack you and if she gets too close in the final scene she will kill you.

Comment: Yup. The final scene where she's running at you is "effectively" a quick time event. I made the mistake of switching to my shotgun. Since everything was in slow-mo, by the time I swapped to the shotgun, she had reached me and 1HKO'd my face.