# Is it possible to kill Dr. Eva while she is running away?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At the end of the first mission on Mars, is it possible to catch the Cerberus agent?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53804/at-the-end-of-the-first-mission-on-mars-is-it-possible-to-catch-the-cerberus-ag)

In the beginning of the game where you go after the prothean blueprints it is being sabotaged by Dr. Eva, she starts running away and you need to follow her. I started firering on her and I noticed her shield takes damage, but because I have to keep following her her shield recharges. Now the question I'm having is: Is it possible to kill her before she gets in the ship? So that she doesn't nearly kill Ashley?

Comment: @agent86 I'm not sure that this is an exact duplicate. The other question asks if it is possible to _catch_ Dr. Eva, while this one specifically asks if it is possible to _kill_ her. As the accepted answer to the linked question is that the person just stayed real close, it doesn't answer if a determined individual can kill her or not.

Comment: @Xantec I agree, because i nearly got her shields down, and i was wondering if it is possible if you loaded a save in the first mission you would sure have enough stopping power.... but allas